# ¿como puedo validar si mi variable $registro hay datos este es mi codigo?

Tags: php, html, sql, html5, phpmyadmin

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRfwR.png)

[image: CODIGO]

Comment: Pepe, bienvenido. Por favor considera [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad. Tu pregunta está mal formulada y podría terminar cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

estas tratando de comparar un objeto mysqli $registro con un entero 0

```
if(registro == 0)
```

lo correcto seria así

```
if(registro)
```